# Drawing a straight line D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I feel like this has a really simple solution but I have been struggling for a while now. I have a d3 line graph and I want to draw a line on the graph that represents the average of the data. I am trying to do this with the line attribute but I keep getting the same errors. The errors I keep getting are:

"Unexpected value NaN parsing y1 attribute.
Unexpected value NaN parsing y2 attribute. "

Here is the code where I try to draw the line:

```
student_av_data.forEach(function(d) { 
     d.student_average = +d.student_average; 
     });

svg.append("line")
    .style("stroke", "orange")
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", y0(function(d) {return y0(d.student_average);}))
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y2", y0(function(d) {return y0(d.student_average);}));
```

`function(d) {return y0(d.student_average);}` should just be a number and that should work in the `y0` arguments.

Not really sure what is wrong. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

As a reference, this works and is basically what I am trying to do but with `d.student_average` in `y0()`:

```
svg.append("line")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("opacity", .2)
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", y0(24))
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y2", y0(24));
```

Comment: `y0(function(d) {return y0(d.student_average);})` is not returning what you think it does, it seems. I'm no d3js expert by any means - what is `y0()`?

Comment: I am almost positive you don't want to call `y0` on an anonymous function. Try `.attr("y1", function(d){ return y0(d.student_average)})` instead (removing the extra `y0` call).

Comment: `y0` is my scale for the y-axis. for reference sake, look at my edit as that is what I am trying to do but with a different value

Comment: Okay, then does the solution in my earlier comment work?

Comment: @mdml trying that I get: "TypeError: d is undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing with this:

```
 svg.append("line")
        .style("stroke", "orange")
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .data(student_av_data)
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", function(d) {return y0(d.student_average);})
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y2", function(d) {return y0(d.student_average);});
```

which will take d from the data elem